# Is it possible to create an NSWindow from the main thread in dart macos?

Tags: macos, dart, grand-central-dispatch, nswindow

I'm currently trying to create a native NSWindow under MacOS using dart (directly, not flutter) in combination with obj-c.
The problem is that all UI things need to be executed on the system main thread while dart is running in a "DartWorker" thread on mac as also outlined here: https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/objective-c-interop#callbacks-and-multithreading-limitations
On that site it is said "You can work around this limitation by writing some Objective-C code that dispatches your call to the main thread", however, when i tried this using GCD the code is never executed both as dispatch_sync and dispatch_async. I assume the main thread is blocked by dart?

I wrote a simple test trying to just log from the main thread in obj-c which is called from dart using a simple ffi function lookup from the dylib:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  NSLog(@"Hello from main %s", [NSThread isMainThread] ? "yes" : "no");
});
```